# Data Replication vs Service Bus vs App Fabric vs...?

Tags: sql-server, architecture, soa

I am build an application which needs to consume data from a source database.  The source database has several issues including:

- Performance issues
- Legacy structure with terrible keys, naming conventions, etc.
- Lots of data my application doesn’t care about

I would like to setup an application specific SQL Server database.  The new database will be populated with a subset of data from the source database (and from a few other source systems).  The data will always move one way from the source databases to the application specific database (i.e. - data won't sync back to the source).  It will have a different DDL model than the source database.
The data doesn't need to be synced absolutely real time, but any longer than a few minute lag could cause issues.
How should I move data from the source database into the application database?  Should I use

- Replication
- Write Custom SSIS Packages
- Abstact to higher level SOA
  solution like nServiceBus, AppFabric, etc?
- Some other ideas?

Pros/cons to each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you don't need a messaging service like NServiceBus - this would involve modifying the legacy system to publish events whenever data changes, something I expect you don't want to get into. Because it is acceptable in your case for your local store of data to be slightly out of date, an SSIS package could be acceptable.

However, if the source database is very large, this could be an issue, as you will be doing it every few minutes. Also, if users of the legacy system are already experiencing performance problems, an SSIS package running every few minutes won't help. Maybe you could introduce a timestamp of the source data, so that it only copies new/modified data?

If the source data is very large and performance is seriously an issue, then maybe NServiceBus would be a good idea. You could also consider Mass Transit or your own simple solution built on MSMQ. But this will mean getting you hands dirty with the legacy code.